# Why won't the shadow cast upon the cube, yet casts upon the driveway?

Tags: lighting, shadows

I've set up a light, and it does cast a shadow, but not upon the green cube. Does anyone have a fix?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: i added a screen shot, but it's not showing up here. lol...

Comment: There is no screenshot in your post. Be sure to add it along with additional information thoroughly explaining the issue and steps you took to arrive where you are, otherwise this question is unanswerable. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: It looks like the "green" texture is connected directly to the material output with no shader (BSDF) in between - this would make it "unshaded" and therefore would not receive any shadows. Go to the shading tab and connect your texture through a shader.

Comment: that's it, thanks. I figured it out... but sheesh. blender. 1 step forward, 2 steps back.

Comment: Hi. I edited your screenshot into the question. I hope you don't mind. Please observe the rules of this platform. It's a question and answer site and there are question and answer post types. You should not post parts of your question as an answer, but instead edit your question and add information to it if needed.